# export content of Listview(s) to CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, listview, export

I have 5 listviews that I want to export it out into one CSV file.

[This is my 5 listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HGxb.png)

In the listview, you can see that the Date Time is the same for all 6 listviews.

So I was able to export the first listview into a CSV File.

```
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv";
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "logs";
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Export to Excel";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (ColumnHeader ch in listView1.Columns)
        {
            sb.Append(ch.Text + ",");
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvs in lvi.SubItems)
            {
                if (lvs.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
                    sb.Append(" ,");
                else
                    sb.Append(lvs.Text + ",");
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        DialogResult dr = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            sw.Write(sb.ToString());
            sw.Close();

            this.Close();
        }
```

Now I want to export the remaining other 4 listview into the same CSV file where the first colomn will be the Date Time which is the same for all 5 listview.

How do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Complete code to accomplish your task

```
class ListViewToCSV
{
    public static void ListViewToCSV(ListView listView, string filePath, bool includeHidden)
    {
        //make header string
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        WriteCSVRow(result, listView.Columns.Count, i => includeHidden || listView.Columns[i].Width > 0, i => listView.Columns[i].Text);

        //export data rows
        foreach (ListViewItem listItem in listView.Items)
            WriteCSVRow(result, listView.Columns.Count, i => includeHidden || listView.Columns[i].Width > 0, i => listItem.SubItems[i].Text);

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, result.ToString());
    }

    private static void WriteCSVRow(StringBuilder result, int itemsCount, Func<int, bool> isColumnNeeded, Func<int, string> columnValue)
    {
        bool isFirstTime = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
        {
            if (!isColumnNeeded(i))
                continue;

            if (!isFirstTime)
                result.Append(",");
            isFirstTime = false;

            result.Append(String.Format("\"{0}\"", columnValue(i)));
        }
        result.AppendLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This example will not work if the listview is in virtual mode; instead you must access each item by its index, and not a foreach loop.